# How to generate instrumented assemblies from one Visual Studio 2013 solution for performance profiling in another solution?

Tags: c#, performance, visual-studio-2013, performance-testing

The "Profile Test" feature of Visual Studio 2013 will only instrument assemblies created by the solution of the unit test being profiled, and will only report function calls define in libraries in that solution. It will not profile or report any function calls that come from refernced libraries built by other solutions.

I have a Visual Studio 2013 solution with some C# library projects and some C# unit test projects. The code references additional C# libraries that are produce by several other VS2013 solutions (think of application code that uses a framework, where the application is in one solution and the framework is in a different solution).

When I start the "Profile Test" operation I see in the output window messages that say "** Instrumented C:...\something.dll **" and so on. Only DLLs built by that solution are logged.

So I assume that the profiler isn't reporting on calls in the assemblies built by a different solution because they are not "instrumented".

Is there any way to build instrumented assemblies that can then be referenced by a different solution? (I've looked but do not find any such option.)

--
Dave Hein